# dynamically add remove image field and insert to database(Remove button not working)

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql

I am running the following line of codes and I can add attachments but when I try to remove it is not working. Please help :(

I tried putting alert on the remove button and it works but I cant seem to click on it to remove the upload attachments.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var html =  '<tr><td><input class="form-control" type="file" name="FileToUpload[]" multiple=""></td><td><input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" name="remove" id="remove" value="Remove"></td></tr>';

        var max = 10;
        var x = 1;

        $("#add").click(function(){
            if (x<max)  {
                $("#table_field").append(html);
                x++;
            }
        });

        $("table_field").on('click','#remove',function(){
            $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
            x--;    

        });

    });
</script>

<h3 class="mt-5">Upload attachments</h3>

<div class="input_field">
    <table id="table_field" class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Image
            </th>
            <th>
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="form-control" type="file" name="FileToUpload[]" multiple=""></td>
            <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="add" id="add" value="Add"></td>
        </tr>                                
    </table>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeGWochAAAAAJJYH17JqaBlkFJfSoJPvrPr2BI0"></div>
    <span id="captcha_error" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean not working into the page or into database?

Comment: Not working into the page. I haven't figure out the insert yet. But the remove button is not working.

Comment: I can keep on adding multiple attachments up to 10 but when I try to remove 1 nothing is happening. I keep on looking at my codes to see If I am missing anything. But I cant find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two big error, the first one you miss `#` into `$("table_field")` and the most important you can't use multiple same `ids` in the same page, use `class/data-attribute` instead like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var html = '<tr><td><input class="form-control" type="file" name="FileToUpload[]" multiple=""></td><td><input class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button" name="remove" value="Remove"></td></tr>';

  var max = 10;
  var x = 1;

  $("#add").click(function() {
    if (x < max) {
      $("#table_field").append(html);
      x++;
    }
  });

  $("#table_field").on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    x--;

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Upload attachments
<div class="input_field">
  <table id="table_field" class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th>
        Image
      </th>
      <th>
        Action
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="form-control" type="file" name="FileToUpload[]" multiple=""></td>
      <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="add" id="add" value="Add"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeGWochAAAAAJJYH17JqaBlkFJfSoJPvrPr2BI0"></div>
  <span id="captcha_error" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you very much. I guess there is something wrong with my eyes. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you! Now to my next problem. How can I insert the file names in the database after renaming each images to avoid duplication.

Comment: Next problem = next try and in case you fail post new question.